# Access parent stack navigator's navigation object from nested child screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am using React Navigation v5 in my react-native project.

I have a nested stack navigator.

The parent stack navigator `MyParentFlow` which has a screen component which hosts another stack navigator:

```
const MyParentFlow = ({route, navigation}) => {

   const MyStack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <MyStack.Navigator
       initialRouteName={...}
       ...>
       {/*HERE is the nested children stack navigator*/}
       <MyStack.Screen
         name={FLOWS.MyChildrenFlow}
         component={MyChildrenFlow}
       />
       <MyStack.Screen .../>
       ...
    </MyStack.Navigator>
)
}
```

My nested stack navigator `MyChildrenFlow`:

```
const MyChildrenFlow = ({route, navigation}) => {

   const MyStack = createStackNavigator();


  return (
    <MyStack.Navigator
       initialRouteName={...}
       ...>
       {/*HERE is a child screen in the nested navigator*/}
       <MyStack.Screen 
         name="MyChildScreen"
         component={MyChildScreen}
       />
       <MyStack.Screen .../>
       ...
    </MyStack.Navigator>
)
}
```

In the child screen hosted by the nested stack navigator:

```
const MyChildScreen =({navigation})=> {
    /* I need to set options for the header of the parent's navigation */
    navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => (
      ...
      />
    ),
  });

}
```

In the child screen hosted by the nested stack navigator, I need to set header via `navigation` for the **parent** navigator. My above code doesn't work because that `navigation` object is the nested stack navigator's , not the parent's.

My question is how can I get access of parent's navigator in the nested child screen and set the navigation options for it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
navigation.getParent().dispatch(
                    CommonActions.navigate({
                            name: 'screenName',
                            params: {},
                        }
                    ))
```

Comment: This is probably the only answer I could find in StackOverflow talking about how to successfully navigate from one nested child into the nested child of another parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with `dangerouslyGetParent()`

```js
const parent = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dangerouslygetparent

Comment: pretty sure it's not. it'd either return a navigation object, or undefined. there's no case where it returns empt object. (source: I maintain react navigation)

Comment: Interesting, I am also pretty sure since the code and logs are in front of me now telling me that `parent` is `{}`. Have you tried? This is what I tried : ```const MyChildScreen =({navigation})=> { const parent = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent(); console.log(`parent: ${JSON.stringify(parent)}`); }``` , logs say `parent: {}`. Very obvious result isn't it? But thank you any way

Comment: I have a feeling that your answer is not for React Navigation v5, if you see my question, I am using React Navigation v5.

Comment: Why are you doing JSON.stringify? The navigation object only contains functions, what do you expect to be in the printed object after you JSON.stringify it? Functions cannot be stringified, so obviously it prints empty object.

Comment: OK, because I don't know that function returns json or not, your answer doesn't tell. I thought it is a json object. And the link you provided also says `This method returns the state object of the navigator which contains the screen. ` Anyway, I tried again without treating it as JSON, the output is `parent: [object Object]`. Is that the `navigation` object of the parent stack navigator? I mean I am asking since I don't know what that [object Object] is. Can I directly `setOptions(...)` with that return?

Comment: The link says "This method returns the navigation prop from the parent navigator that the current navigator is nested in", also I answered that to your question specifically asking for navigation object, why would I need to repeat it in my answer? Yes you can call setOptions on it because it's the navigation object. You can just try it in your code, it'd take 2 seconds.

Comment: Right. Thank you!

Comment: Try `this.props.navigation.getParent.setOptions`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#getparent